# Simplification changes the output?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if I have a function $ f(x)=\frac{2x}{x+1}$ I can simplify it to $f(x) =\frac{2}{1}=2$

But this changes the function for example $ f(10)=\frac{20}{11} $ which is not equal to 2. 
Does this mean if I simplify a function it will become a different function?

Comment: We have $\frac{2x}{x+1} \neq 2$ for all $x \neq -1$. What do you mean by "simplify"?

Comment: You cannot simplify it in that way.

Comment: Why can't I get rid of the x?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$f(x) - 2 
= \frac{2x}{x+1} - 2
= \frac{2x-2(x+1)}{x+1}
= \frac{2x-2x-2}{x+1}
= \frac{-2}{x+1}
$$

Remember that

$$\frac{a}{b} - c
= \frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{1}
= \frac{a - b c}{b}
$$